# Read Json in android

Tags: android, json

```
{"721xxxxxxx":true,"722xxxxxxx":true,"723xxxxxxx":true}
```

How can i read all the keys in the json and how can count all the data in the Jsonarray

My code-->

```
String members = s;
/* s contain {"721xxxxxxx":true,"722xxxxxxx":true,"723xxxxxxx":true} */
JSONArray jsonChildArr = new JSONArray(members);

Log.e("Error","Data in jsonArray--->"+jsonChildArr.length());
```

Comment: That a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`

Comment: JSONARRAY having length property.. this is json Object, you don't have length method

Comment: your string {"721xxxxxxx":true,"722xxxxxxx":true,"723xxxxxxx":true} is an jsonobject not jsonarray .

Comment: Your string is a JSONObject, not JSONArray. JSONObject is not designed for iterating. You should complain about the backend implementation.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between jsonobject and jsonarray

Comment: is my answer not correct?

Comment: ak sacha your answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do Like this.**

```
try {
            String members = s;
/* s contain {"721xxxxxxx":true,"722xxxxxxx":true,"723xxxxxxx":true} */

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(members);

        JSONArray array = obj.names();

        Log.d("ItemCount",array.length()+"");

        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
            Log.d("Item",array.getString(i)+":"+ obj.getBoolean(array.getString(i));
        }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your welcome :) Happy Coding :).. and  You can upvote too so other can get help from it.

Comment: i tried to vote it but has less reputaion to consider by system

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Way to Read JSON Object**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(members);
Log.i("Data","Data in jsonObject--->"+jsonObject.getBoolean("721xxxxxxx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
   boolean data = jsonObject .getBoolean("721xxxxxxx");
   Log.d("Data","data:"+data );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 String jsonStr = "{"721xxxxxxx":true,"722xxxxxxx":true,"723xxxxxxx":true}";
JSONObject itemJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr );

 HashMap<String,Boolean> result = new HashMap<>();
 while(itemJsonObj.keys().hasNext()){
  //parse json and save as key-value.
  result.put(itemJsonObj.keys().next()+"",itemJsonObj.get(itemJsonObj.keys().next());
```

// result.size() is like array's size.

}

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for parsing and generating JSON in Android http://github.com/amirdew/JSON

for your sample:

```
JSON jsonData = new JSON(jsonString);
int count = jsonData.count();
```